# On apple ipad icon leave some space and because of that it shows some black background color behind that icon. why this?

Tags: ios, ipad, ionic2

I have made square shape icon for ipad, and also ipad make icon  in rounded shape automatically on app, but in my app, it shows some black background color behind the icon.
please reply me..

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you are using rigt size? Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/app-icon/). It would be also nice if you put an image here.

Comment: i have made icon using right size,and same icon are properly managed with iphone device, but problem is only for ipad..